# Chrome extension converting backbone.js collections to regular JavaScript array

Tags: backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, backbone.js-collections

In my background script:

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse(new collection());
}
```

In my browser_action's javascript:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    action: "someAction",
    tab: tab 
  },  
  function(collection) {
    // collection is now a JS array, rather than Backbone.Collection
  }); 
});
```

As mentioned in the comment above the 'collection' argument in the sendRequest callback turns out to be a regular JS array, rather than Backbone.Collection.

Is this a sanitisation artefact / security measure taken by chromium? Is there any way to pass a Backbone.Collection via sendRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`onRequest` documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) it says that the argument to `sendResponse` should be a JSON-ifiable object, so I'm assuming that the Collection's `toJSON` method is being called, leaving you with just the data.

If you have the Collection definition in the target script you could instantiate a new object with the same data.